# Community как автор причин закрытия в инструментах модератора

Tags: дефект, поддержка, локализация, 10k-tools

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tools/question-close-stats

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я так понимаю, там должен быть [Дух сообщества](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/%D0%94%D1%83%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0)?

Comment: Подозреваю, что причины закрытия хранятся в денормализованном виде, а в 14м году Духа сообщества так и звали.